# $http.post function protype (AngularJs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I want to know the prototype of post function ($http.post()).
How many parameter it takes and which are they?
As per my understanding post(url,data).

Answer (score -2):

on the method post you have 3 parameters (url, data, [config])

$http.post(url, data, [config]);

In the documentation explain this:

[angular post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

Comment: Sorry I don't know it, I fix it.